# Multilevel (up to 3 level) Vertical Menu with bootstrap/Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a navigation menu which is vertical and up to 3-level navigation and last level is toggable menu (when u click on last level menu,a set of submenu appears below that).A sample structure of the menu structure is similar to this

[image]

I tried below code but doesn't getting desired output

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Optional theme
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
         -->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

            .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
                margin-top: -6px;
                margin-left: -1px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
                -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
                border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
                display: block;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
                display: block;
                content: " ";
                float: right;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-color: transparent;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
                border-left-color: #ccc;
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-right: -10px;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
                border-left-color: #fff;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
                float: none;
            }

                .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
                    left: -100%;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3 column margintop20">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

                <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Client Advice</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pre-advice</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Strategy & Technical</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                            <a href="#">APL & Products</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu parent">
                                <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        Approved Product List
                                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="display:none;"></span>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="child">
                                        <li style="padding:10px 15px;">Platforms</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Managed Funds</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><a href="#">Model Portfolios</a></li>
                                <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><a href="#">Non-approved Products</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Execution Only</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Personal Development</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Practice</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.child').hide(); //Hide children by default

        $('.parent').children().click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).find('span').toggle();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to create a vertical multilevel menu structure using bootstrap,jquery I haven't got any multilevel menus with vertical orientation .Facing css issues with this code,not able to create similar navigation menu.

Comment: I know this is not like your mockup, but this might be helpful: http://thecodeplayer.com/experiment/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3/3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but it's what I would do in your case.

I use sometimes bootstrap but, as good as it is, in my humble opinion, people are very often thinking it's a miraculous code that can make you do whatever you want, and lately I am finding people spent more time trying to modified bootstrap css's than making the whole css's from scratch (if you know a bit of basic css), not to say so many webs "looking" so simillar.

For what you want to do I would basically clearing ALL classes in the html and just sniping the elements from the container I could do a menu as you show in the image (well, it needs some extra style like adding the arrow icons, shadows and such, but the point is to show you another way to do it).

html:

```
<div class="container">        
            <ul class="">

                <li class="">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Client Advice</a>
                    <ul class="">

                        <li class=""><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pre-advice</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Strategy & Technical</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="#">APL & Products</a>
                            <ul class="parent">
                                <li >
                                    <a href="#">
                                        Approved Product List                                        
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="child">
                                        <li >Platforms</li>
                                        <li >Managed Funds</li>
                                        <li >Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li >Wealth Protection</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                        <li >Listed Securities</li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Model Portfolios</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#">Non-approved Products</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Execution Only</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="#">Personal Development</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Practice</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
```

And just this css (please notice that when I call directly a `<a>` tag you may need to call it a different way:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.container {
    height:100%;
}
a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
li {
    padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
.container ul {height:100%;}
.container > ul {
    width:250px;
    background-color:#224490;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}
.container > ul > li {}
.container > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#18316a;
}
.container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul >li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:-250px;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#112551;
}
.container > ul > li > ul > li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.container > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover {background-color:#0f1e41;}
.container > ul > li > ul > li ul li ul li {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

And I have just kept the classes that activate the script so keep it untouched.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/9m60mx6r/7/)**

I hope this can be usefull for you. 
Feel free to ask any question or if you want something you want to modified (and you can't after, of course, trying) I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Definitely agree with Bootstrap not being the silver bullet that so many people believe that it is. "I can use Bootstrap, so I don't need to learn CSS!"

Comment: if you look into attached lockup,last 3 menus are fixed at bottom,how to handle this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "fixed at bottom". Can you explain it, please?. And btw you have changed the original image (the one my example looks like). It could be better to add anoher image to your question than change it without an "edit" note. Now and for future users my answer looks much less elaborate,

Answer (score 6):

you can make it like your screenshot: http://codepen.io/MaGiO/pen/YXXzeJ

HTML

```
<div id="mn-wrapper">
        <div class="mn-sidebar">
            <div class="mn-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            <div class="mn-navblock">
                <ul class="mn-vnavigation">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Client Advice</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pre-advice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Strategy & Technical</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu active">
                                <a href="#">APL & Products</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu parent">
                                    <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            Approved Product List
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="display:none;"></span>
                                        </a>

                                        <ul class="child">
                                            <li style="padding:10px 15px;">Platforms</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Managed Funds</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Wealth Protection</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Wealth Protection</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                            <li style="padding: 10px 15px;">Listed Securities</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </li>
                                    <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><a href="#">Model Portfolios</a></li>
                                    <li style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;"><a href="#">Non-approved Products</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Execution Only</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Personal Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Practice</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right collapse-button" style="padding:7px 9px;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="mn-cont">
            <div class="cnt-mcont">
                <h1>Title Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    html{
        height:100%; /* make sure it is at least as tall as the viewport */
    }
    body{
        height:100%; /* force the BODY element to match the height of the HTML element */
        position: relative;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #mn-wrapper {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .mn-sidebar {
      display: table-cell;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-bottom: 49px;
      background: #272930;
      width: 216px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    #mn-cont {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;

      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .cnt-mcont {
      background-color: #F6F6F6;
      color: inherit;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 200;
      line-height: 21px;
      padding: 15px 30px 30px 30px;
      margin-top: 0;
      height: 101vh;
    }
    .mn-sidebar .mn-toggle {
      display: none;
      padding: 10px 0;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .mn-vnavigation {
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid #1a1c20;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #2f323a;
    }
    .mn-vnavigation li a {
      border-top: 1px solid #32353e;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1c20;
      display: block;
      padding: 14px 18px 13px 15px;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height: 101vh;
        width: 216px;
        background: #272930;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

JS

```
$('.child').hide(); //Hide children by default

    $('.parent').children().click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.child').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).find('span').toggle();
    });
```

you want something like this?

Comment: if you look into attached lockup,last 3 menus are fixed at bottom,how to handle this?

Comment: i've update the code, try to look here: [update code](http://codepen.io/MaGiO/pen/YXXzeJ)