# Responsive Multilevel Menu

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, single-page-application

Can anyone help in providing code for responsive multilevel menu. I have created a responsive SPA and now I want to modify the menus to multilevel. Here is a `plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/NPHsIoirRJA1pS7KNopn?p=preview. I want submenus to be included for both the menus here (dashboard,tab1).

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888018/multilevelupto-3-level-vertical-menu-with-bootstrap-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put your menu items into an unordered list and then your dropdown menu items into another unordered list and then style them accordingly.

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li>
            <a ui-sref="#">Tab</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a ui-sref="page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="page3">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You can see an example of this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0A55Sb4qjS0tap6tavJL?p=preview