# ASP MVC How to add multiple sub levels?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need my menu to look like this

```
link1   link2
        link3
        link4
            link5
            link6
```

Here is my markup

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Index", "Link1")</li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link2<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Index", "Link3")</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link4<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Link5", "Index", "Link5")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Link6", "Index", "Link6")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name</p>
</div>
```

But this is what I get

[image]

Link 4 never expands to show the sub links (link5 & link6)

Any ideas?

Comment: This to me seems to be more of a CSS-related question than ASP.NET specific. The default ASP.NET project template uses Bootstrap css framework (hence the class names in your example), so if you want to stick to it, I would suggest to search for something like "bootsrap 3rd level menu" and perhaps check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multilevel(upto 3 level) Vertical Menu with bootstrap/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888018/multilevelupto-3-level-vertical-menu-with-bootstrap-jquery)